# Redirect from node page after form submission?

Tags: nodes, 7, entities, redirection

When editing some fields, after I click the save button, I want the page to redirect to a particular page. Is there any module for this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the module [Node save redirect](https://drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect)

> This module provides a method of specifying a location to take the
>   user after saving a piece of content. A set of radios buttons are
>   added to the submission vertical tab on the content type edit form.
>   The available options are. Default - Default behaviour Return to Edit
>   page after saving Return to content overview page (assuming the user
>   has access permissions Re-redirect to another location. (any valid
>   drupal path)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to simply implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and put this code into it:

```
    function MY_THEME_OR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      // dpm($form_id)
      // dpm($form)
      if($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_node_form_submit';
      }
    }

    function my_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      $form_state['redirect'] = 'MY_URL';
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules). Go to admin/config/workflow/rules. Add a new rule
 [image]-

react on event = saving new content.

[image]

Specify the content type this rule will work on.

[image]

Add an action to the rule -

[image]

in this case redirect page (under system - page redirect) -

[image]

and then add in the url of the redirect or use tokens. Plus rules has the added benefit of being useful for other things than just redirects.

[image]